# How can I see the actual SQL an ASP SqlDataSource will run (after binding)

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, sqldatasource

This is a very simple question, but one I can't find an answer to. If I have an SqlDataSource that takes parameters, how can I see the actual SQL that will be executed against the DB after the binding takes place? (I have tried adding a breakpoint to code on the onBinding event of the SqlDataSource)

Thanks for any help

Ryan

Comment: Is this for a selection, delete, or update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a profiling tool at the database end to get the actual SQL executed. For Sql Server you can use [Sql Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The `SqlDataSource.SelectCommand` should show you the text of the command that will be executed.